# Installing docker on RPi 3B+ with CentOS?

Tags: docker

I'm using the latest CentOS release on my RPi and I'd like to start playing with docker. I tried following the official instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#install-docker-ce). I installed the dependencies and enabled the repo, but when I tried to run `sudo yum install docker-ce`, I got the following error:

```
https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/armhfp/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

Does this mean there is no docker build for CentOS on the RPi? If not, what's the easiest way to make this happen?

Comment: I have installed it successfully. You can try this. https://www.deeplearn.site/learning-diary/205.html

Answer (score 3):

If You need install Docker at RPI3 + CentOS, run next command

```
sudo yum install docker -y
```

add Docker to startup - `sudo systemctl enable docker.service`
Run Docker - `systemctl start docker`

Answer (score 1):

Not many OS distros package docker for the CPU architecture of the RaspberryPi - armhf. Your error indicates that CentOS doesn't have a docker package for you.

You will need to install it like this:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh
```

This is further explained in this raspberrypi.org article:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/docker-comes-to-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is docker for CentOS uses `armv7l` as identifier for the 32 bits architecture and the raspberry tries to install the `armhfp` architecture because that is the value that outputs `$basearch` variable.
That's why you get a `404` when you try to install docker after adding your docker repo.

In order to solve it you need

- Add the docker repository.
- Go inside of the `/etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo` and update the
  `$basearch` with `armv7l` and comment the reference to the
  `docker-ce-stable`because at least today(2020-06-11) there is no a
  stable version.
- Then you need to install docker with: `yum install docker.armv7hl`

Answer (score 0):

rm /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo

vim /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo

```
[docker-ce-nightly]
name=Docker CE Nightly - armv7l
baseurl=https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/$releasever/armv7l/nightly
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/gpg
```

yum update && yum install -y docker